# Anonymous Type Behavior

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Can you explain the behavior of why this code produces this result?

```
var person = new { name = "George", age = 30};
WriteLine(person);
```

And Output is:

`{ name = "George", age = 30}`

Comment: What would you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WriteLine(object)` implicitly calls `ToString()` on the underlying object.  The method is virtual, meaning it can be overridden by derived types.

Anonymous types override `object.ToString` to show their properties and values.  The compiler generates the overridden method, and it can't be changed at compile-time or run-time.

Comment: Thanks i will chose best answer.